# Crash on calling GetFocusedElement from a thread

Tags: winapi, microsoft-ui-automation

I have an Electron app with a native node module written in C++, built with MSVC compiler and linked using CMakeJS.

The node module has hook callbacks installed (`SetWindowsHookEx`) in separate threads for a mouse click (`WH_MOUSE_LL`) or a keydown (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`). It calls `GetFocusedElement` whenever the user clicks or presses a key. The call is retried three times with a `Sleep(10)` in case the return code is `UIA_E_ELEMENTNOTAVAILABLE`.

Is there any particular pre-condition for `GetFocusedElement` that I need to enforce to avoid this fatal crash? I have checked [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-getfocusedelement) and I didn't find any such precondition. I would prefer to avoid any fatal crashes even if that means not finding any focused element.

**Error trace:**

```
OS Version: Windows 10.0.19044 (3086)
Report Version: 104

Crashed Thread: 10164

Application Specific Information:
Fatal Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ / 0xffffffffffffffff

Thread 10164 Crashed:
0   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46cdfe2      LocalUiaNodeProxy::RealRemoteNodeFromProviderEntryPoint
1   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46fb1fb      LocalUiaNodeProxy::RemoteNodeFromProviderEntryPoint
2   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46fb15e      LocalUiaNodeProxy::RemoteNodeFromProviderEntryPoint
3   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb47267c5      UiaNodeFactory::InProcProxyFromHwnd
4   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb471a47a      ClientProxyManager::InternalGetProxyProvider
5   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb471a087      ClientProxyManager::GetProxyProvider
6   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb4709767      UiaNodeFactory::CompleteNodeInfo
7   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb4708289      UiaNodeFactory::FromPartialNodeInfo
8   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb472643c      UiaNodeFactory::FromLocalProvider
9   uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb472654f      UiaNodeFactory::FromLocalProvider
10  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46e8b4f      UiaNode::ProviderDrillForPointOrFocus
11  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46e84e4      UiaNode::ProviderDrillForPointOrFocusInternal
12  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46e83f1      InProcClientAPIStub::UiaNode_DrillForPointOrFocus
13  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46c60fd      ComInvoker::CallTarget
14  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46fa998      InProcClientAPIStub::InvokeInProcAPI
15  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb46be327      UiaNode::CrossProcess_DrillForPointOrFocus
16  uiautomationcore.dll            0x7fffb4778d7b      CUIAutomation::GetFocusedElement
17  nativeapp.node                  0x7fffdec1187d      GetFocusedElementRetry (iohook.cc:182)
18  nativeapp.node                  0x7fffdec1432f      focusChangeHandler (iohook.cc:304)
19  nativeapp.node                  0x7fffdec0fbfa      <lambda>::operator() (iohook.cc:779)
20  nativeapp.node                  0x7fffdec0c70d      [inlined] std::invoke (type_traits:1564)
21  nativeapp.node                  0x7fffdec0c70d      std::thread::_Invoke<T> (thread:55)
22  ucrtbase.dll                    0x7fffe3b91bb1      thread_start<T>
23  KERNEL32.DLL                    0x7fffe48d7613      BaseThreadInitThunk
24  ntdll.dll                       0x7fffe63c26f0      RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: CUIAutomation is a COM object marked as "both" in terms of threading support, so it's callable from any thread. However, UIAutomation itself is using hooks so maybe there's some race condition, hooks are always a bit hacky. From your stack it seems UIA runs from its own thread (?) but have you tried (at least for testing) to run UIA in another process (with an infinite 10ms loop)

Comment: Check this doc, does it help?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-obtainingelements Also there is a classic sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/UIAutomationDocumentClient

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks. We tested by running the GetFocusedElement method in a separate thread 2000 times at 10ms intervals, and manually changing the focused element across different apps like notepad/outlook/chrome/calculator. The function did not crash any time. The HRESULT value was consistently 0. Any insights on this?

@Torrecto-MSFT Thanks. I checked the samples don't have anything about `GetFocusedElement`. I checked the documentation and it did not state any precondition or edge cases for the `GetFocusedElement` function.

Comment: Not really but it doesn't suprise me that much, like I said hooks are always dangerous, I usually just run very thin pieces of codes in there, delegating all real work to other threads.

Comment: @GaurangTandon There is indeed a lack of Pre-Condition. The doc says Clients should handle errors from this method gracefully; for example, by trying the call again. Try the call again. Hahaha....

Answer (score 0):

The error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ always happened when the structed object didn't get the correct memory address and can't be read as a completed structed object
In this case, would you please check the parameter IUIAutomationElement **element and make sure it was generated correctly.